# How to get the column name in nattable?

Tags: nattable

I had create an example like Editor Example, while the difference is that my demo can hide column. While when I hidden some column, I can not the collect selected column index, I changed my mind, I want to get the selected column's header name. How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the handler to handle the selected column

But I don't know how to get the column name

```c
public void handleLayerEvent(ILayerEvent event) {
    if (event instanceof CellSelectionEvent) {
        CellSelectionEvent cellEvent = (CellSelectionEvent) event;
        int columnIndex = natTable.getColumnIndexByPosition(cellEvent.getColumnPosition());
        SelectionLayer selectionLayer = cellEvent.getSelectionLayer();
        ........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the reference to the ColumnHeaderLayer and get the data value. E.g. ColumnHeaderLayer#getDataValueByPosition(int, int)